# Query erases all entries instead of the ones selected

Tags: mysql, joomla

I made a dropdown menu that is populated from the joomla database. The menu contains names of peaks from a specific user. This part works smoothly. 
When the user selects the peak name from the dropdown menu and click the delete button, query should only delete the row with the id of the specific user ($link_id) and the name of the selected top ($vrh_name2).

In my case, query deletes all rows of this user regardless of the name of the selected top

Where did I make a mistake?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo '<div class="sender">';
$link_id = JRequest::getInt('link_id'); 
echo '<h4>Form for delete peak</h4>';

// Creating Dropdown menu from database
   
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query2 = $db->getQuery(true);
$query2->select('peak_name');
$query2->from($db->qn('#__climbing'));
$query2->where($db->quoteName('#__climbing.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
$query2->order('peak_id ASC');
$db->setQuery($query2);
$peaks_list2 = $db->loadColumn();
$peaks_select2  = '<select name2="name2" id2="peaks">';
$peaks_select2 .= '<option value="">-- Select peak for delete --</option>';

foreach($peaks_list2 as $p2){
    $peaks_select2 .= '<option value="' . $p2 . '">' . $p2 . '</option>';  
}
$peaks_select2 .= '</select>';
?>

<form name="lista2" method="post" action="">
<?php echo $peaks_select2; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Delete" />
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
$vrh_name2 = $_POST['name2'];

// Delete peak query

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$q_4 = $db->getQuery(true);
$q_4->delete($db->quoteName('#__climbing'));
$q_4->where($db->quoteName('#__climbing.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id))." AND ".($db->quoteName('#__climbing.peak_name')." = ".$db->quote($vrh_name2));
$db->setQuery($q_4);
$db->execute();
}
echo '</div>';
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not forget [some of the past advice that I have offered](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23211/12352).

Most noticeable in this question, `$peaks_select2  = '<select name2=` will not work.  The `name` attribute must be unadulterated.

By performing the potential delete action first, you can allow your users to make delete after delete and always see the most up-to-date data in the select.

I don't like that you are using `peak_name` as your identifier.  Your table has a `peak_id`, these are expected to be auto-incremented and unique in most cases and they are how professionals associate related data. (You should alter your design to adopt this practice.)

When an option's `value` attribute value is the same as the option's text value, there is no need to declare the `name` attribute.  Because I am suggesting the use of the ids, I am declaring the `name` attribute.

Untested snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// get the $_POST['submit'] value; if missing, set as empty string (WORD is a Joomla-specific filter that strips unwanted characters for security reasons)
$action = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('submit', '', 'WORD')

// get the $_POST['peak_id'] value; if missing set as 0 (INT strips any character that is not a digit)
$peak_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('peak_id', 0, 'INT');

// try to get the $_POST['link_id'] value; if it is missing, try from $_GET['link_id']
$hiker_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('link_id', 0, 'INT');
if (!$hiker_id)
{
    // there was no submission (this is the first load of the page)
    $hiker_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get->get('link_id', 0, 'INT');
}
echo "<div>Link Id: $hiker_id</div>";

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

if ($action === 'Delete' && $peak)  // if action is Delete and $peak is not empty or 0
{
    $delete_query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->delete("#__climbing")
        ->where([
            "link_id = " . (int) $hiker_id,
            "peak_id = " . (int) $peak_id
        ]);
    $db->setQuery($delete_query);
    $db->execute();
    if ($db->getAffectedRows())  // check for successful deletion (if at least one row was deleted)
    {
        echo "<div>Successfully deleted row for hiker#: $hiker_id, peak#: $peak_id</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div>Failed to delete row for hiker#: $hiker_id, peak#: $peak_id</div>";
    }
}

// now query the table for the fresh data after the (potential) delete was performed
$peaks_query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select("peak_id, peak_name")
    ->from("#__climbing")
    ->where("link_id = " . (int) $link_id)
    ->order("peak_id");
$db->setQuery($peaks_query);

$peaks_select = '<select name="peak_id">';
$peaks_select .= '<option value="0">-- Select peak to delete --</option>';
if (!$results = $db->loadAssocList())  // there were no rows in the result set
{
    // no peaks found for $link_id
}
else
{
    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
        $peaks_select .= "<option value=\"{$row['peak_id']}\">{$row['peak_name']}</option>";  // create option with name as text and id as the value
    }
}
$peaks_select .= '</select>';

// print the simple form...
?>
<div class="sender">
    <h4>Peak Delete Form</h4>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <?=$peaks_select?>
        <input type="hidden" name="link_id" value="<?=$hiker_id?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: My php knowledge is low and I do not know how everything works. I tried this code and did not work and I could not find why. But your advice about select name2=  has helped me. There was a mistake. Thanks a lot

Comment: It is my responsibility as a poster to explain anything that is confusing about my answer.  You are welcome to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: I don0t understand how work this: $peak_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get->get('peak_id', 0, 'INT'); because i have error unknown variable $peak_id

Comment: OOOH, I made a mistake!  I was trying to get `peak_id` using `$_GET` but it should be `$_POST`.  Thank you.

Comment: @Midhat I just made several corrections.  Please click on my Edit History (to the left of my picture) to see the highlighted changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i understand you attemps and with this information based on :

- https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

You can perform delete with this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo '<div class="sender">';
$link_id = JRequest::getInt('link_id'); 
echo '<h4>Form for delete peak</h4>';

// Creating Dropdown menu from database
.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query2 = $db->getQuery(true);
$query2->select('peak_name');
$query2->from($db->qn('#__climbing'));
$query2->where($db->quoteName('#__climbing.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
$query2->order('peak_id ASC');
$db->setQuery($query2);
$peaks_list2 = $db->loadColumn();
$peaks_select2  = '<select name2="name2" id2="peaks">';
$peaks_select2 .= '<option value="">-- Select peak for delete --</option>';

foreach($peaks_list2 as $p2){
    $peaks_select2 .= '<option value="' . $p2 . '">' . $p2 . '</option>';  
}
$peaks_select2 .= '</select>';
?>

<form name="lista2" method="post" action="">
<?php echo $peaks_select2; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Delete" />
</form>
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
  {
     $vrh_name2 = $_POST['name2'];

     // Delete peak query
     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $q_4 = $db->getQuery(true);
     // delete all row where this conditions link_id and peak_name
    $conditions = array(
        $db->quoteName('link_id') . ' =' . $db->quote($link_id)), 
        $db->quoteName('peak_name') . ' = ' . $db->quote($vrh_name2))
    );
    $q_4->delete($db->quoteName('#__climbing'));
    $q_4->where($conditions);
    $db->setQuery($q_4);

    $db->execute();
}
echo '</div>';
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also does not work. Delete everything in the table

Comment: @Midhat, sorry i didn't have platform for test. I have update code for test

Comment: Thanks @pascal sanchez
Now does not delete anything

Comment: Maybe it's a misunderstanding because of my bad English language, but it does not work yet. Now when I select the item for delete  and I click delete does not delete anything